# What is the formula AUTO ARIMA (Python's pmdarima) uses?

Tags: python, arima, seasonality, intercept

### References

https://otexts.com/fpp3/non-seasonal-arima.html
https://otexts.com/fpp3/seasonal-arima.html

### Question

According to the webpages, the formula of `ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)[m] with intercept and drift` should be like below. However, the result of `auto_arima` function and the result I calculated using the formula below didn't match. Can anyone teach me the correct formula?

#### Formula

$$
(1-\Sigma^p_{i=1}\phi_iB^i)(1-\Sigma^P_{i=1}\Phi_iB^{im})(1-B)^d(1-B^m)^Dy_t=intercept+drift*t+(1+\Sigma^q_{i=1}\theta_iB^i)(1+\Sigma^Q_{i=1}\Theta_iB^{im})\epsilon_t
$$

#### How to calculate

1. The model generated by `auto_arima` was `ARIMA(2,0,0)(1,0,2)[12]`.
2. The formula I calculated is below.
   $$
   (1-\phi_1B^1-\phi_2B^2)(1-\Phi_1B^{12})y_t=intercept+drift*t+(1+\Theta_1B^{12}+\Theta_2B^{24})\epsilon_t
   $$
   $$
   y_t=\phi_1y_{t-1}+\phi_2y_{t-2}+\Phi_1y_{t-12}-\phi_1\Phi_1y_{t-13}-\phi_2\Phi_1y_{t-14}+intercept+drift*t+\Theta_1\epsilon_{t-12}+\Theta_2\epsilon_{t-24}+\epsilon_t
   $$
3. The code is like below.

```
import pmdarima as pm
model = pm.auto_arima(data, trend='ct') # `data` contains actual values, and is prepared in advance.
print(model.resid()) # this is used to get \epsilon values.
```

4. Simply remove $\epsilon_t$ and substitute all $\phi, \Phi, \Theta, \epsilon, y, intercept, drift$. However the result didn't match. I'm suspecting the formula I calculated was wrong.